# Provide different values per component for same service

Tags: angular, angular-services, angular-providers

I am not sure if I am getting the concept of services, injectors and providers wrong, but I was thinking that I could do the following:

I have a service that validates digits for me (calling a method, passing in a digit that should be validated...). I want to adjust the validation depending on some information that I want to pass to the service. Like: What is the max. amount of digits. Are negative values allowed. I know I could pass these informations into the validation-Method as parameters, but I was thinking if there is something more global?

I read about Injectors and managed to Inject these parameters like this:

```
 constructor(@Inject('negativeValues') @Optional() private negativeValues,
              @Inject('maxDigits') @Optional() private maxDigits) {}
```

And it does work, when add providers in my module, where my component is calling this service.
But what if another component in the same module needs to provide different information?

Would the best way, splitting it into smaller modules (which I wouldn't prefer) or is there a chance, that I can provide these values per component (or at least override the existing - though adding these providers to the component, didn't work for me).

Or is there a better way to provide values to a service, without passing them into the method?

Comment: Have you considered `useFactory` provider? You can make use of `deps` property to inject other providers and decide upon what provider should this component get.

Comment: I haven't heard of `useFactory`yet, but I sounds interesting and will give it a loo, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Julia, one service is unique for all the application (well, really it's not true, you use the "provideIn" to create a service for each module or foreach application)

So I suppose you has a service and some functions in service. You pass to the functions service's the parameter

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root', //<--here indicate if the service is unique
                      //for the application or if is for a module
})
export class DataService {

  constructor() { }
  formatNumber(negativeValues:boolean,negativeValues:number,maxDigits:number)
  {
         ....
         return result
  }
}
```

And you call from your component like

```
  constructor(dataService:DataService){} //<--inject in constructor
  //in any time
  const result=this.dataService.formatNumber(true,2,3)
```

NOTE: you can also has in a .ts differents functions (use "export" to indicate can be exported)

```
export function formatNumber(negativeValues:boolean,negativeValues:number,maxDigits:number)
      {
             ....
             return result
      }
    }
```

And in component

```
import { formatNumber} from "./myfunction"; //<--the file.ts where ou has the functions
//and in any where
const result=formatNumber(true,2,3)
```